# How can I get the timestamps from a log table, when some state changes?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a list of state changes which happen at differnet dates:

```
create table log (
  date date not null,
  state int not null default 0
);

insert into log (date, state) values
  ('2015-06-01', '0'),
  ('2015-06-05', '1'),
  ('2015-06-09', '1'),
  ('2015-06-10', '0'),
  ('2015-06-11', '0'),
  ('2015-06-14', '1'),
  ('2015-06-16', '1'),
  ('2015-06-26', '1'),
  ('2015-06-27', '0'),
  ('2015-06-28', '0'),
  ('2015-06-30', '1');
```

How can I get the pair of dates where the state changes?

Expected output:

```
date 1,       date 2,       state 1,  state 2
'2015-06-01', '2015-06-05', 0,        1
'2015-06-09', '2015-06-10', 1,        0
'2015-06-11', '2015-06-14', 0,        1
'2015-06-26', '2015-06-27', 1,        0
'2015-06-28', '2015-06-30', 0,        1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible query for the state changes is:

```
select pair.date as "date 1", pair.nextdate as "date 2", pair.state as "state 1", log.state as "state 2"
  from
    (select cur.*, min(next.date) as nextdate
      from log as cur
      join log as next on cur.date < next.date
      group by cur.date, cur.state) as pair
    join log on log.date = pair.nextdate
  where pair.state <> log.state;
```

**Explanation**

By joining log with itself on the condition `a.date < b.date` we get a list of
pairs of dates.

```
select * from log as cur
  join log as next on cur.date < next.date
  order by cur.date, next.date;


cur.date,     cur.state, next.date,    next.state
'2015-06-01', 0,         '2015-06-05', 1
'2015-06-01', 0,         '2015-06-09', 1
'2015-06-01', 0,         '2015-06-10', 0
'2015-06-01', 0,         '2015-06-11', 0
'2015-06-01', 0,         '2015-06-14', 1
'2015-06-01', 0,         '2015-06-16', 1
'2015-06-01', 0,         '2015-06-26', 1
'2015-06-01', 0,         '2015-06-27', 0
'2015-06-01', 0,         '2015-06-28', 0
'2015-06-01', 0,         '2015-06-30', 1
'2015-06-05', 1,         '2015-06-09', 1
'2015-06-05', 1,         '2015-06-10', 0
```

If we take the minimum of `next.date` we get the timestamp of the date after
`cur.date`.

```
select cur.*, min(next.date) as "nextdate"
  from log as cur
  join log as next on cur.date < next.date
  group by cur.date, cur.state;

date,         state, nextdate
'2015-06-01', '0',   '2015-06-05'
'2015-06-05', '1',   '2015-06-09'
'2015-06-09', '1',   '2015-06-10'
'2015-06-10', '0',   '2015-06-11'
'2015-06-11', '0',   '2015-06-14'
'2015-06-14', '1',   '2015-06-16'
'2015-06-16', '1',   '2015-06-26'
'2015-06-26', '1',   '2015-06-27'
'2015-06-27', '0',   '2015-06-28'
'2015-06-28', '0',   '2015-06-30'
```

To get the `state` for `nextdate` we join `log` again and filter for state
changes (`pair.state <> log.state`).